# Subtracting 30 days from an ISODate using MomentJS

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am trying to use MomentJs to take a given ISOdate, subtract 30 days from this date then use MomentJs isAfter method to check whether the date is within the last 30 days. I thought I had written this logic correctly but the subract method does not remove 30 days from the ISODate I i give it as shown here:

```
cosnt deceasedDate = '2021-12-23T23:00:00.000Z';
const thirtyDaysAgo = moment(deceasedDate)
  .subtract(30, 'days')
  .startOf('day');


try {
  if (!moment(deceasedDate).isAfter(thirtyDaysAgo)) return;
```

If I breakpoint after assigment of deceasedDate it has not been altered. It still has the value '2021-12-23T23:00:00.000Z'.

Can anyone see why this may be happening? I presumed I was able to pass an ISODate to Moment so the date got wrapped by Moment.
Thanks

Comment: _"If I breakpoint after assigment of deceasedDate it has not been altered"_ - Why should a immutable string, stored in a `const` variable ever change?

Comment: also typo here `cosnt deceasedDate`

Comment: I think you mean `const thirtyDaysAgo = moment()` (assuming you mean from now

Comment: Your code work correcly, moment doesn't edit `deceasedDate` (it's a const too, so it's impossible to edit without give you an error), if you log `thirtyDaysAgo.format()` it logs the correct date of 30 days ago `2021-11-24T00:00:00+01:00`.
My sugestion is to use `isBetween()` instead of `isAfter()` if you want compare a thirth date between other 2 dates

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working just as it should.
Look at the output from the snippet, it does subtract 30 days from the given date. And return true or false if checked using isBefore or isAfter.

```js
const deceasedDate = '2021-12-23T23:00:00.000Z';
const thirtyDaysAgo = moment(deceasedDate)
  .subtract(30, 'days')
  .startOf('day');

console.log(thirtyDaysAgo.toISOString());
console.log(!moment(deceasedDate).isBefore(thirtyDaysAgo));
console.log(!moment(deceasedDate).isAfter(thirtyDaysAgo));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```